# Copy NuGet contentFiles transitively to referenced project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet package in which is an extra file packaged as a **Content** in `contentFiles` folder.

Then I have two C# projects with SDK-style .csproj - A and B where **Project B** references **Project A** as a `ProjectReference` and there is a classic `PackageReference` of a **NuGet package** in the **Project A** like this:

**NuGet package ← Project A ← Project B**

My problem is that the extra file gets correctly copied to the build output of Project A, but it won't get copied to the output of Project B unless I do it manually.

**Is there a way how to force copy the extra file from the NuGet dependency transitively to the Project B build output?**

The only way I can think of is custom **Post-build event** with `xcopy` command but it's more of a workaround than a real solution.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Do you see 2 projects inside one solution (Project A and B, where B is a main project)?

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, those 2 projects are within 1 solution.

Comment: Have you tried to set the order of compilation (available under the context menu in project explorer -> project dependencies)?

Comment: Do you mean a build order of the projects? It's set correctly, first, Project A is built and then Project B, otherwise, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't reproduce your issue. I've created 2 projects - as you mentioned. ProjectA is using content.txt file placed in contentFiles folder. Then i've created ProjectB and i added ProjectA to solution of ProjectB and then i added a reference to Project A. In ProjectA i've changed `CopyToOutputDirecoty` property for content.txt file to 'Always copy' and that file is copied to output directory of ProjectB. See: [VS: Copying files to Debug or Release folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx)

Comment: No no, you didn't understand my question. I have a NuGet package where the file is located and then the package is referenced in Project A which is a reference in Project B in the same solution. Try to create some dummy NuGet package and add it as a reference to Project A.

Comment: @MartinVrábel Are you in control of the NuGet package with the content files?

Comment: @MartinVrábel, i've tried. Also NuGet packages and also dummy files. I have got one solution with 3 projects in it. Each sub-project is using some NuGet package. All files related to that packages are copied to the build (bin) folder of main folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If you are in control of the NuGet package

You can add additional build targets in which you are able to specify that the content files should be copied.

Add `build/MyNuGetPackage.targets` to the NuGet package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>

    <!-- For all files in /contentFiles -->
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\contentFiles\**\*.*">
      <!-- Copy to output directory on build -->
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>

  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This will copy all content files of this package into the output folder, including cases where this package is transitively referenced.

Comment: Thank you, Bruno! I already had a .targets file for this but obviously in a bad format. After changing it to your suggestion, it magically works! Thanks a ton.