# How to transitively copy files to output across NuGet packages?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a `PackageA` that needs a file to be copied to the output of the final application to work as expected.
I include the needed file into my `PackageA`'s project with these lines:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="test.txt">
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If I consume the generated package directly, the file `test.txt` is copied to the output.

Now, if I reference this `PackageA` from another `PackageB`, and reference only the `PackageB` rather than `PackageA`, the file `test.txt` is not copied at all to the output while I expected this file to be transitively copied.

I tried digging into the issues of the NuGet/Home repository and found that we should play with the `PrivateAssets` or something like that ([Issue on github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12270) and all its siblings). But I never succeeded in making this work.

I made a [github repository to show off the issue I'm facing](https://github.com/lmorvan/nuget-transitively-copy-to-output).

I also know that it is possible to copy the file by including `.props` or a `.targets` file doing so with a pre-build or post-build action, but I find this solution quite hacky, not elegant, and hard to set up and maintain over time. Moreover, I do have the feeling that NuGet is supposed to support this kind of usage quite easily, so maybe I have missed something somewhere.

On StackOverflow, there are also many posts about transitive copy. However, as far as I dig, it always talks about packages that are directly consumed by a project, or a tree of projects. My issue is a package referenced by another package itself referenced by a project.

Comment: This question was also posted on github NuGet/Home repository : https://github.com/NuGet/Home/discussions/12523

Comment: It seems no one is interested in this question 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you could use the dependency control flow by adding metadata to your project reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets

In PackageB.csproj

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="../PackageA/PackageA.csproj">
    <PrivateAssets>analyzers;build</PrivateAssets>
</ProjectReference>
```

contentFiles should then be in the included assets

Comment: Thanks a lot! When putting these lines into the project, the generated nuspec changes the `include` attribute of the `dependency` tag. The nuspec reference is not very explicit about that, but here is it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to suggest taking a look at [Copy NuGet contentFiles transitively to referenced project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143283/copy-nuget-contentfiles-transitively-to-referenced-project), but it seems the solution is with .targets, so not quite what you are looking for.

Comment: Check this too: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6151

Comment: This post talks about transitivity through projects not through packages. However, it is interesting as it completes the full workflow.